# Query regarding syncing data across iPhones or iDevices for a user

Tags: ios, swift, icloud, cloudkit, nspersistentcloudkitcontainer

I have a photo album app that uses core-data. As of now it does not utilise login nor do I plan to.
My requirement is that the album should sync across a user's multiple iDevices.
I was watching https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/202/ (Using Core Data With CloudKit) where it says it is pretty straightforward to do so.
Also, this https://developer.apple.com/icloud/cloudkit/ says that the limit is 10GB. I'm kinda confused here, does the 10GB count towards all of my users *combined* storage capacity or is it *per* user ? Hoping that its the latter.
Can someone also let me know if I'm on the right path or not with respect to using Cloudkit?

Comment: It seems that you are asking several questions under one topic.

Comment: The 10GB limit is for *public cloudKit* - This is storage associated with and accessible to all users of your app.  Core Data in CloudKit is stored in the user's private iCloud storage and counts to *their* iCloud limit (either the free limit or any additional storage they have subscribed to)